# Open The Standard "Find Network Printer" dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, .net-2.0

I am writing a winform application on .NET 2.0 that i need to open the popup that let user select a printer in LAN. It's exactly NOT a PrintDialog. I just need a popup same as the popup with title "Please select the network printer you want to use and click Select to connect to it" when you click on "Find Printer..." button of PrintDialog.

A popup like [this](http://imageshack.com/a/img15/3098/ebhr.jpg)

Anyone can help me to open this popup without opening a PrintDialog popup?

Comment: This was many years back, Were you able to find a solution to this ?, this is exactly what I would need.

Comment: Yeah, such a long time. In fact i don't remember the solution but i have solved it with below suggestion from Alex. I am not sure i still keep the code or not. I would share the exact code if i found it.

Comment: yes please, if you could, that would be of great help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to isolate that portion of the print dialog.

You probably need to use WMI, and write a function to accomplish what you want. I had to write something similar recently.

This function will populate all of the printers on a specified computer and list them in a combobox. I've set it to where it listed the printers as `\\servername\\printername` for my purposes, but feel free to edit it as you need.

I hope this helps.

```
private void getPrinters(string domain, string username, string password, string server, ComboBox cmbBox)
    {
        progressBar.Maximum = 3;
        progressBar.Step = 1;
        ConnectionOptions objConnection = new ConnectionOptions();
        objConnection.Username = username;
        objConnection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + domain;
        objConnection.Password = password;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + server + @"\root\cimv2", objConnection);
        try
        {
            scope.Connect();
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            MessageBoxButtons msgButton = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            MessageBoxIcon msgIcon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
            string msgText = "Cannot connect to " + serverPrint + ".";
            string msgTitle = "Connection Error";
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(msgText, msgTitle, msgButton, msgIcon);
            return;
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBoxButtons msgButton = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            MessageBoxIcon msgIcon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
            string msgText = "Bad Username or Password.";
            string msgTitle = "Authentication Error";
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(msgText, msgTitle, msgButton, msgIcon);
            return;
        }
        SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery();
        selectQuery.QueryString = "Select * from win32_Printer";
        ManagementObjectSearcher MOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, selectQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection MOC = MOS.Get();
        cmbBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in MOC)
        {
            string itemName = @"\\" + serverPrint + @"\" + mo["Name"].ToString();
            cmbBox.Items.Add(itemName);
        }
    }
```